# Oven igniter replacement blew immediately

Tags: oven

Our oven stopped preheating a couple days ago. I am thinking that it was the igniter, since when I use a multimeter to check it, it alternates between 1 and an actual reading. It doesn't seem to have consistent continuity. The multimeter doesn't seem to be at fault because if I test other things it works fine.

I ordered and installed this replacement part. It claims to replace part number 316428500 which is what the old igniter is. --> [https://www.amazon.com/Repairwares-5304509706-PS12071409-Norton-501a-WB02X10016/dp/B08JFGMB47](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JFGMB47) Oven model is Frigidaire FGF366DCE.

After installing, I tried preheating the oven again. It seemed to work at first, but after a few minutes, there was an electrical pop sound and a bright flash in the oven. There was also a plastic burning smell. I immediately turned off the oven, disconnected the plug, and shut off the gas. Then upon inspecting the new ignitor, the element had totally blown off.

Is this just a shame on me for buying a cheap replacement part, or could this indicate that something else is wrong with the oven?

Comment: Or you could have accidentally touched the element when you installed it - this could cause it to explode (like halogen lights)

Comment: Agree with @ DJ., but wondering about the plastic smell.  I wouldn't expect to find plastic components anywhere near the oven interior, let alone the burner/ignitor or the wires connecting it.  The ignitor wires go through a hole in the oven wall.   I would follow them and look at all associated wiring and the switch or relay that controls the power to the ignitor.  (Or maybe "plastic burning smell" was not actually plastic but either some contaminant that got on the element while you were installing it or just the incineration of the element itself.)